# Issues building MySQL Connector/C++ with MinGW

Tags: mysql, build, mingw, mysql-connector

I am having issues building MySQL Connector/C++. These should be due to my environment, which does not seem to be fully supported by MySQL: Windows 7 and MinGW.

At first I installed MySQL Server 5.5 and MySQL Connector/C++ from binary packages. However this requires to develop with Visual C++, since this is the tool used to obtain these binaries.

So I am using the same MySQL Server 5.5 (installed from binary), but building MySQL Connector/C++ from source with MinGW:

```
mysql-connector-c++-1.1.0> cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DBOOST_ROOT:STRING=C:\Boost\include\boost-1_48 ENV{MYSQL_DIR} = "C:\Program Files\M
ySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include"

CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/include" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
```

So the CMakeLists.txt file is missing from MySQL.
Could this be due to the fact I installed MySQL from a binary package?
Should I build it from source to get this file?
Is it possible to do it with MinGW?

MySQL Connector/C++ needs MySQL C Connector to be present. Is this present in the standard MySQL package?

*Thank you for your help!*

Comment: Use vcpkg instead :)